# Stripe Plans JSON string formatting

Tags: php, stripe-payments

When I read all Plans from Stripe API I'm getting below response

```
Stripe_List JSON: { "object": "list", "has_more": false, "url": "\/v1\/plans", "data": [ { "id": "999999999", "interval": "month", "name": "10MB \/ Month", "created": 1409893899, "amount": 9900, "currency": "usd", "object": "plan", "livemode": false, "interval_count": 1, "trial_period_days": null, "metadata": [], "statement_description": "Inc" } ] }
```

How I can remove the **Stripe_List JSON:** from the response.

here is my php code

```
function GetAllPlans(){
    require_once('./stripe-php/lib/Stripe.php');
    Stripe::setApiKey($this->APIKEY);       
    return Stripe_Plan::all();
}
```

here is the code for calling the function

```
echo $objstripe->GetAllPlans();
```

Comment: According to their documentation, it returns an associative array. Are you sure you are not converting to json and adding that string yourself?

Comment: No, I'm not adding, its just return like this

Comment: I can remove that string in Android but, how its possible in php side?

Comment: It should not be there and the result should not be a string to start with: https://stripe.com/docs/api#list_plans. Most likely you have a problem in your code somewhere else.

Comment: is this code will make problem "echo $objstripe->GetAllPlans();"

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment, you are using:

```
echo $objstripe->GetAllPlans();
```

Your `GetAllPlans()` method returns an [associative array](https://stripe.com/docs/api#list_plans) and you can't just echo an array.

Assuming that you want json, you should use:

```
echo json_encode($objstripe->GetAllPlans());
exit;
```

That will [encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) your associative array to a json string that you can pass to your Android application.

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but getting the response like "{}"

Comment: @AbleAlias Check the value of `Stripe_Plan::all()`. If that is a non-empty array, `json_encode()` will not return an empty object string.

Comment: if I use this code "echo $objstripe->GetAllPlans();" getting the result as mentioned on the question, if I use this code "echo json_encode($objstripe->GetAllPlans());" getting empty result

Answer (score 0):

I expect the problem is because you only include the Stripe library within the function, but you return Stripe_Plan objects out of the function. When that data is received outside of the function, the PHP script doesn't have access to the PHP library, so it wouldn't understand the object type.

Personally, I don't see the benefits of having a function just call a Stripe function; I'd do away with the construct entirely and just invoke the Stripe method directly when needed.

Hope that helps,
Larry

PS I work on Support at Stripe.